# Заполнить таблицу enum с помощью JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enum

Есть два класса `enum` и класс содержащий его как атрибут.

```
public enum Grade {
    _1("1"),
    _2("2"),
    _3("3"),
    _7bPLUS("7b+"),
    _7c("7c"),
    _7cPLUS("7c+"),
    _8a("8a"),
    _8aPLUS("8a+"),
    _8b("8b"),
    _8bPLUS("8b+"),
    _8c("8c"),
    _8cPLUS("8c+"),
    _9a("9a"),
    _9aPLUS("9a+"),
    _9b("9b"),
    _9bPLUS("9b+"),
    _9c("9c");

    private String name;

    Grade(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Связь между ними многие к одному, то есть множество экземпляров `Itinerary` могут иметь один уровень `Grade`

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Itinerary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;

    private Integer length;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Sector sector;


    private Grade grade;
}
```

Можно ли как-то пометить аннотациями что-бы hibernate автоматически создавал таблицу Grade с полями id и name. И при этом заполнял ее. Так как создать не проблема, я просто мой enam делаю @Entity добавляю id поле и ставлю над атрибутом в классе аннотацию @ManyToOne. Но таблица grade при этом остается пустой, хотя мне ведь известны ее значения с самого начала.

Можно ли ее заполнить при старте?

Comment: Возникает законный вопрос: зачем вам таблица в базе если значения статические?

Comment: Нормализация данных, я хочу вынести повторяющиеся значения в отдельную таблицу.

Comment: Зачем? Места вы не сэкономите. Ключи больше займут.

Comment: Я конечно новичок и может что-то не понимаю, но разве мы не должны повторяющиеся данные при нормализации бд группировать в отдельной таблице?

Comment: Это философский вопрос. В данном случае удобнее не хранить их в отдельной таблице.

Comment: Хорошо, возможно вы и правы, но все-же есть ли возможность заполнения таблицы enum при инициализации бд?

Comment: Только если вручную. Автоматически нет. Нужно написать бин который на старте будет проверять таблицу и заполнять если чего-то не хватает. Но это не будет работать с энумом.

Comment: Спасибо, можете написать ответ, чтобы я смог закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Готово. Добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым простым решением в данном случае будет не создавать новой таблицы вовсе.

Хотя это и формально нарушает правила для 3-ей нормальной формы, в данном случае соображения практичности перевешивают.

Если же действительно нужна таблица, то с энумом это работать не будет.

Придется создать полноценную сущность и написать бин который при старте будет проверять содержимое таблицы и заполнять ее если требуется.